# Opencart 2.1 нету способа выбора доставки

Tags: php, opencart

Нужно добавить способы доставки в интернет магазине https://kalibri.top/ при оформлении заказа. В админке добавил модуль доставки и включил его в разделе Дополнения-Доставка. В товарах стоит галочка "необходима доставка". Но при оформлении заказа шага способов доставки нету. После заполнения личных данных сразу перекидывает на шаг "Способ оплаты". Мне кажется что его вырезали в самом шаблоне или скрипте. Как проверить?

Comment: для таких целей есть модули

Comment: Модуль доставки я поставил, но проблема в том что он не выводится + сам блок доставки.